# Geoserver Explorer cannot connect to Geoserver returning error 404

Tags: qgis-plugins, geoserver-explorer

This is to share my experience on a problem I had and how I solved it:

I have just installed GeoServer and it works fine, however, I wanted to give a try to the GeoServer Explorer but it could not connect to GeoServer. I am not sure what I have done wrong.

I am using Windows 10 and QGIS 2.18.4 . I get the following error when trying to create a new catalog from QGIS:

Tried to make a GET request to http://localhost:8080/Geoserver/Web/rest/workspaces.xml but got a 404 status code: 
HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /Geoserver/Web/rest/workspaces.xml. Reason: 
    Not Found

---

Powered by Jetty:// 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\gui\explorer.py", line 101, in run
    command(*params)
  File "C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\gui\gsexploreritems.py", line 551, in populate
    raise e
FailedRequestError: Tried to make a GET request to http://localhost:8080/Geoserver/Web/rest/workspaces.xml but got a 404 status code:

HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /Geoserver/Web/rest/workspaces.xml. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

By default Geoserver Explorer used the following link to connect: 
http://localhost:8080/Geoserver/Web/ and I took it for granted. After trying many things, I realized that the default URL was wrong: instead of http://localhost:8080/Geoserver/Web/ it should had been 
http://localhost:8080/Geoserver/ and now I can access Geoserver.

[image]